# jQuery Mobile Hosted on Server 1 and Retrieve Data from Server 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jQuery Mobile application that is hosted on Server 1. It includes some php pages that query a database hosted on Server 2.

This all works fine when everything (jQuery Mobile website and Database) is hosted on the same server but when they are separated it doesn't display any of the data. The php page essentially queries the database and retrieves 20 records then outputs these as html, e.g.:

```
<div data-role="content">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
        <? echo $output; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

$output is just a php variable with the list view of the records in the format that jQuery Mobile expects.

Anyone know how I can get this php page to work when it is hosted on Server 1 which is accessing data hosted on Server 2.

I think the problem is security related - when the database is on server 2 jQuery Mobile is preventing the request due to something related to cross domain requests? I'm getting un "unknown error" when attempting to retrieve the data from the database which isn't particularly helpful.

If I put the same getContacts.php page on Server 1 and remove all the jQuery mobile components so it it just a straight php page which queries the database on server 2 and outputs html it works perfectly.

UPDATE: I found this page: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

which discussed the allowCrossDomainPages option which is set to false by default. I would like to try overriding this and setting this to true but not sure how - anyone know how to set this override? I'm not familiar with jQuery unfortunately, just using jQuery Mobile as is.

Comment: Edit after question update: jQuery doesn't care where the data originally came from (if your PHP is outputing formated html/javascript). You're probably doing something wrong (e.g. syntax error). Show us your code

Comment: The syntax is fine - the same page works fine when the database/website are on the same server. The page also works fine when not part of the jQuery Mobile site.

Comment: Yes, I would firstassume so too in the same situation. But there's clearly no problem querying the data either (you understand how PHP and html works right?) It doesn't hurt to show us more of your code. For example, inspect the 'generated' html (with jQuery mobile components)

Comment: I think the problem is security related - when the database is on server 2 jQuery Mobile is preventing the request due to something related to cross domain requests? I'm getting un "unknown error" when attempting to retrieve the data from the database which isn't particularly helpful

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing. If the PHP does all the querying and just creates a formatted web document, there should be no problem. If you're making an Ajax request to a different domain, that's a different story (look into CORS - setting the proper headers on your server 1 page). Although you've mentioned nothing about an ajax request

Comment: Thanks - I started comparing the headers and as I understand it jQuery Mobile makes the AJAX request automatically and this works fine for same origin/domain requests but is blocked by cross domain requests. My database server is not even receiving the request from the php page on server 1 - it's getting blocked by jQuery Mobile. Now I have to figure out if there's some setting in jQuery Mobile that can override this. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Check out this link : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a PHP `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://server2.example.com')` should work (put this on the page with the jQuery making the request - at the top of the page before any content is sent)

Comment: Thanks - I tried that but got the same result. I think it might be related to the allowCrossDomainPages option discussed here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: I too read about the cors option in jQuery before too - without luck (maybe I was doing it wrong). It's not something you should easily be able to set with javascript - for a security (which is why the server must specify what is allowed). Try using Google chrome (I find that console the best), and `ctrl shift j` to open the javascript console. Then you can see what sort of errors there are